# npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core@5.11.0 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ionic4, ionic-native

Below error shows when I tried `ionic cordova build android --prod`

I have done this and did many times.

```
 rm -rf node_modules/ 
 rm -rf platforms/ 
 rm -rf plugins/
```

Removed `package.lock.json` and tried `npm i` But no luck yet. Any clue?

**Error**

> $ ionic cordova build android --prod
>
> > cordova.cmd platform add android --save Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@8.0.0 Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@8.0.0
> >     Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is
> >     incorrect. Check your connection and platform name/version/URL. Error:
> >     cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: npm ERR! Windows_NT
> >     10.0.17763 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "D:\Clients\ionic4\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
> >     "install" "cordova-android@8.0.0" "--production" "--save-exact" npm
> >     ERR! node v12.4.0 npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12 npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core@5.11.0 does not
>   satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements! npm ERR!
>   peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/android-permissions@5.11.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/document-viewer@5.11.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/file@5.11.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/file-opener@5.11.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm
>   ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/file-transfer@5.11.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/firebase-x@5.11.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm
>   ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/geolocation@5.3.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/http@5.3.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR!
>   peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/in-app-browser@5.2.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/launch-navigator@5.11.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/network@5.3.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/screen-orientation@5.4.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0
>   npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/splash-screen@5.0.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@5.0.0 npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer
>   @ionic-native/status-bar@5.0.0 wants @ionic-native/core@5.0.0 npm ERR!
>   peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/vibration@5.7.0 wants
>   @ionic-native/core@^5.1.0
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Clients\ionic4\npm-debug.log
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mho.lla" version="0.1.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>lla</name>
    <description>lla App</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">m-hospitality</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="Hostname" value="localhost:8100" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8100/*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
        <string>We use your location for full functionality of certain app features.</string>
    </edit-config>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="3.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-ionic-xhr" spec="^2.1.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-advanced-http" spec="2.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="4.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="3.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" spec="3.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebasex" spec="latest" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx" spec="1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="1.1.0" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="5.0.4" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~5.0.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~8.0.0" />
</widget>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "lity",
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "7.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "7.0.0-beta.23",
    "@angular/forms": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "7.2.2",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/android-permissions": "^5.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/document-viewer": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-opener": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/firebase-x": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/http": "5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "5.2.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "5.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "5.3.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "5.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0",
    "@ionic-native/vibration": "5.7.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "4.0.0",
    "@types/underscore": "1.9.2",
    "cordova-android": "8.0.0",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.4",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "2.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": "1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx": "1.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cocoapod-supportx": "1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": "0.9.11",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebasex": "latest",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "3.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.4.4",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "4.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "3.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-vibration": "3.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.4",
    "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-ionic-xhr": "2.1.1",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "3.2.1",
    "cordova-support-android-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "1.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "ionic4-rating": "1.0.9",
    "js-sha1": "0.6.0",
    "latest": "0.2.0",
    "leaflet": "1.4.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "5.0.4",
    "underscore": "1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.12.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.13.9",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "7.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "7.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "7.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "7.2.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "7.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "1.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.36.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/leaflet": "1.4.3",
    "@types/node": "10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "8.0.0",
    "tslint": "5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-ionic-xhr": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-advanced-http": {
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.10.0"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": {},
      "cordova-plugin-vibration": {},
      "cordova-plugin-android-permissions": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": {
        "GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID": "AIzaSyAPpI438",
        "OKHTTP_VERSION": "3.12.0",
        "LOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "This app requires access to your location for navigation purposes"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-document-viewer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-firebasex": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was dev environment. I didn't use the latest `Ionic CLI` and `Cordova CLI`. After I updated those then no issues and I was able to build the `APK`.

```
$ ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.4 (C:\Users\Sampath\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.3
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 20 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:

   NodeJS : v12.4.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 2.15.12
   OS     : Windows 10
```